# Logging actions of my powershell into a file

Tags: powershell, logging, replace, path, rename

I'm actually doing a script to replace every "o" into my folder/files names into "0"

Here is my simple script :

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse |`
Where-Object { $_.name -match 'o' } |`
Rename-Item -NewName { $_name -replace 'o', '0' }
```

It is working but now I want to log into a file every files/folder that have changed. 
So basicly I want to add a function to write the name of my file before and after being renamed.

For example, for the "BEFORE name", I tried to add this command after the Where-Object pipe :

```
Add-content $MylogFile
```

It succed to log every files having a 'o' inside but WITHOUT their path. And having a log of 1000+ files without their path is useless...

DO you have any idea to simply log the before/after name of each file that have been renamed by the script WITH their path ?

Thanks in advance ! 
Regards,

Comment: Use `-passthru` switch after `rename-item` cmdlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to store the original search into a variable then iterate over it. The following should do what you want:

If you want to rename only files:

```powershell
$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIscontainer -eq $false -and $_.name -match 'o' }
$files | % { 
  $newname = $_.name -replace 'o', '0'
  write-host "Before: $($_.fullname)"
  write-host "After: $newname"
  $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newname
}
```

To rename files **AND** folders:

```powershell
$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIscontainer -eq $false -and $_.name -match 'o' }
$files | % { 
  $newname = $_.name -replace 'o', '0'
  write-host "Before: $($_.fullname)"
  write-host "After: $newname"
  $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newname
}
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIscontainer -eq $true -and $_.name -match 'o' }
$dirs | % { 
  $newname = $_.name -replace 'o', '0'
  write-host "Dir Before: $($_.fullname)"
  write-host "Dir After: $newname"
  $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newname
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer, but the problem remains the same with this code.
I executed it into my test folder wich contain multiple files called o.txt (Into sub-folder, sub-sub-folder, etc..)
And the ouput is still like this for every files :
    Before : o.txt 
    After : 0.txt
There is no path, just the file name.

Comment: Ok I found a way ! I replaced this line in your script 
    "Before: $($_.name)" 
By 
    "Before: $($_.Fullname)"
As someone proposed, and it works !
But there is still one problem, If the script try to rename a file into a folder that he renamed before, it say the path for the file doesn't exist anymore (because the folder as been renamed and he is using  its old name in the path)

Comment: Do you want to also replace the folder names too then, or just the files?

Comment: Both. The second option was the good one, it works perfectly,just changed "Write-Host" to "add-content $log". Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.